# Groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample of my data:[Data Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB57m.png)

My problem statement is :  I have to find top 20 languages with maximum requests

I want to do this using Pandas.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and slice first 20

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  language page_name  requests  bytes
0       en         a         1    220
1       eu         b         1    620
2       eu         b         1    620
3       tr         c         1    780
4       en         d         4    620
5       en         e         9   1320

In [5]: df.groupby('language')['requests'].sum()
Out[5]:
language
en    14
eu     2
tr     1
Name: requests, dtype: int64

In [6]: df.groupby('language')['requests'].sum()[:20]
Out[6]:
language
en    14
eu     2
tr     1
Name: requests, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Or `.head(20)` instead of slice, though I am not really sure which is better.

Comment: sum does not sort, so you need to `.order(ascending=False)` before head. Edit: Nope, you want to use `.nlargest(10)`.

Comment: Thanks John Galt. That worked for me. I just had to use sort(ascending = False) at the end. Thanks again